# Keyboard shortcut increase/decrease font size when using Guake?

Tags: guake

Is there a keyboard shortcut to increase or decrease the font size while using Guake?

I have it in Guake preferences through a few clicks but if I am doing a presentation and the audience as a tough time seeing then I want to be able to do something similar to what a browser does with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel scroll</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Make a script file with the following line.

```
gconftool-2 --type string  --set /apps/guake/style/font/style 'DejaVu Sans Mono 10'
```

Change the value '10' to whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Akazuko's answer [I wrote a script](https://github.com/ajhepple/guake-font-size) that can be used to increase or decrease Guake's font size. Mapping this to `<Ctrl><Shift>+` and `<Ctrl><Shift>-` respectively gives the 'zooming' behaviour I wanted and which I think you wanted.